# How to clear exception mask

Tags: c++, exception, iostream

When creating an *exception mask* for a file, should an exception throw during a file operation, I can reset the state bits of the actual file using `ios::clear()`.

Though after doing so, will the *exception mask* still throw an exception, thinking that the specified error state flags are still set to true? If so, how can I reset the *exception mask* so that it is ready to throw more exceptions should the appropriate situations arise in the future?

Nothing in the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/) for `ios::exceptions` does it say that the *exception mask* will/won't continue to throw exceptions after one of the specified error state flags go off.

**The overall question is:**
Should an *exception mask* throw an exception after which the related file's error state flags are cleared through the use of `ios::clear`, will the *exception mask* still throw exceptions (assuming `ios::clear` didn't set off another error state flag itself)? If so, how do I prevent it from doing so by resetting it/clearing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *exception mask* doesn't throw exceptions.  What throw exceptions are all the actions which modify the stream's state if after the modification there is at least one set bit in the state corresponding to a set bit in the exception mask.

So if you use `clear` in such a way that it set a bit which is present in the exception mask, an exception will be throwed.

Comment: So if for example, my exception mask is is set to compare `failbit`, and after a failed operation, `failbit` is set, hence throwing an exception;
By calling clear, should I expect another exception to be thrown since the value of `failbit` was changed once more? Or will an exception only be thrown if (in this case) `failbit` is set to true?

Comment: Yes, exceptions are thrown if the bit is true.